# Is there any way to fix models appearing as just verts?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have had three models import this way. The mesh isn't visible on any mode, and I cant seem to  find any solutions via searching it. Is there anyway to fix them?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Not really... looks like the object was just consisting of a point cloud without any edges or faces. You cannot magically make Blender detect which vertices should be connected and which not, although some might be obvious but not necessarily all. What kind of file format did you import? Can you open it in any other viewer software and it shows faces correctly?

Comment: What is the file format you are importing from?
In support of the previous comment it is better to check your export settings and generate a new file for importing in Blender.

Comment: These were all PMX files I had gotten online, and I'm not sure of any other way to open the models as I am new to messing with 3d models.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make the models still usable, sadly its at the cost of the armature. I just need to use a converter and turn the pmx to an fbx.